# Create subnets with tag Name that include the AZ of the subnet using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am creating a VPC using terraform VPC module,
and trying to give the subnets names that make sense like: `data-vpc-private-subnet-a`,
the "a" represents the availability zone that the subnet is located in.

but I am not sure how to do that, this is what I have so far:

```
module "vpc" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"

  name = "${local.name}"
  cidr = "10.70.0.0/16"

  azs             = ["${local.region}a", "${local.region}b"]
  az              = ["a", "b"]

  private_subnets = ["10.70.1.0/24", "10.70.2.0/24"]
  public_subnets  = ["10.70.3.0/24", "10.70.4.0/24"]

  manage_default_network_acl = true
  default_network_acl_tags   = { Name = "${local.name}-default-nacl" }

  manage_default_route_table = true
  default_route_table_tags   = { Name = "${local.name}-default-route-table" }

  manage_default_security_group = true
  default_security_group_tags   = { Name = "${local.name}-default-sg" }

  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  enable_dns_support   = true

  map_public_ip_on_launch = false
  enable_nat_gateway      = true
  enable_vpn_gateway      = true
  single_nat_gateway      = false
  one_nat_gateway_per_az  = false
  reuse_nat_ips           = true                    # <= Skip creation of EIPs for the NAT Gateways
  external_nat_ip_ids     = "${aws_eip.nat.*.id}"   # <= IPs specified here as input to the module

  # VPC Flow Logs (Cloudwatch log group and IAM role will be created)
  enable_flow_log                      = true
  create_flow_log_cloudwatch_log_group = true
  create_flow_log_cloudwatch_iam_role  = true
  flow_log_max_aggregation_interval    = 60

  tags =     var.vpc_tags
  private_subnet_tags = { Name = "${local.name}-private-subnet-${az[count.index]}" }
  public_subnet_tags = { Name = "${local.name}-public-subnet-${az[count.index]}" }

}
```

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: You cannot reference the variable that is defined for the module in that way. What you could do is define your variabile, `variable "az" {}` and then try that way. The `count.index` will not work for sure as you don't have the `count` meta-argument defined for the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a great help from @Maciej Rostański answer, I was able to give the subnets their own unique names.

To also won't have to get rid of the tags I wanted to put on all the resources I used each resource default-tag.

So this is what I got at the end:

```
module "vpc" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"

  name = "${local.name}"
  cidr = "10.70.0.0/16"
  azs = slice(local.azs, 0, 3)

  private_subnets = ["10.70.1.0/24", "10.70.2.0/24"]
  public_subnets  = ["10.70.3.0/24", "10.70.4.0/24"]

  manage_default_network_acl = true
  default_network_acl_tags   = var.default_network_acl_tags

  manage_default_route_table = true
  default_route_table_tags   = var.default_route_table_tags

  manage_default_security_group = true
  default_security_group_tags   = var.default_security_group_tags

  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  enable_dns_support   = true

  map_public_ip_on_launch = false
  enable_nat_gateway      = true
  enable_vpn_gateway      = true
  single_nat_gateway      = false
  one_nat_gateway_per_az  = false
  reuse_nat_ips           = true                    # <= Skip creation of EIPs for the NAT Gateways
  external_nat_ip_ids     = "${aws_eip.nat.*.id}"   # <= IPs specified here as input to the module

  # VPC Flow Logs (Cloudwatch log group and IAM role will be created)
  enable_flow_log                      = true
  create_flow_log_cloudwatch_log_group = true
  create_flow_log_cloudwatch_iam_role  = true
  flow_log_max_aggregation_interval    = 60
  # Additional tags
  vpc_tags                   = var.vpc_tags
  nat_eip_tags               = var.nat_eip_tags
  nat_gateway_tags           = var.nat_gateway_tags
  private_acl_tags           = var.private_acl_tags
  igw_tags                   = var.igw_tags
  vpc_flow_log_tags          = var.vpc_flow_log_tags
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the public vpc module, subnet tags are defined in the module like this (example for public subnets):

```
    "Name" = format(
        "${var.name}-${var.public_subnet_suffix}-%s",
        element(var.azs, count.index),
      )
```

So in the main module you would have to set up:

```
data "aws_availability_zones" "zones" {}

locals
{
  [...]
  azs = data.aws_availability_zones.zones.names
}

module "vpc" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  [...]

  name = "my-project"
  azs = slice(local.azs, 0, 3)
  
}
```

and then the name od the subnet is e.g. `my-project-private-eu-central-1a`.

If you mean to get rid of the region and leave only `a`, then you would have to download the module, modify lines that define tags (for example `main.tf` line 394 for private networks) and use this code as a local module source:

```
  tags = merge(
    {
      "Name" = format(
        "${var.name}-${var.private_subnet_suffix}-%s",
        replace(element(var.azs, count.index), var.region ,""),
      )
    }
```

The above code removes region from the subnet's name, provided of course that you also push the `region` variable into the module.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but  in this way I can not add any other tags on the module resources. and I can not use the "tag" element

Answer (score 2):

There's another solution available: You can use `public_subnet_tags_per_az` and `private_subnet_tags_per_az`.

Your code should look like this:

```
  public_subnet_tags_per_az = {
    "${local.region}a" = {
      Name : "${local.name}-public-subnet-a"
    },
    "${local.region}b" = {
      Name : "${local.name}-public-subnet-b"
    },
    "${local.region}c" = {
      Name : "${local.name}-public-subnet-c"
    }
  }

  private_subnet_tags_per_az = {
    "${local.region}a" = {
      Name : "${local.name}-private-subnet-a"
    },
    "${local.region}b" = {
      Name : "${local.name}-private-subnet-b"
    },
    "${local.region}c" = {
      Name : "${local.name}-private-subnet-c"
    }
  }
```

I'm not sure if `"${local.region}a"` etc. would work; however, with AZ names directly, it works as expected.